# Android - How can I print the result in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

I shoul use setText() but how should I use it instead of System.out.println()?
I want to print the result in a TextView. The code is a json reader. sorry I need to write some text to let me post my question.

```
public class JsonReader extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("display"));
    //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tv );
    //tv.setText(json.toString());
    //tv.setText(json.get("display"));

}
```

}

Comment: You haven't used any text view in your code

Comment: Have you defined any textview in your activity_main layout?

Comment: Where is your textview.

Comment: Clairvoyant -> yes, but I can't setText from java.

Comment: What's the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: @tinysunlight I want to print a json in a textView.

Comment: Can you see your R.layout.activity_main in mobile?

Comment: @tinysunlight yes why not?

Comment: I think you can just move code from main to onCreate() .I post a answer.

Comment: In main(), you can't findViewById() because it's static and it knows nothing about layout.It means that if you haven't open a JsonReader, you can also use JsonReader.main to run your code.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to print the result in a TextView if you want to view the result on phone instead of LogCat console as suggested by johnrao07.

To print result in a TextView first add a TextView widget in activity_main.xml layout file.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then JsonReader.java class main function instead of `System.out.println(json.toString());` call `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)).setText(json.toString());`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Logs** to print and debug stuff in android.

Generally there are **five methods**,

```
Log.v() Log.d() Log.i() Log.w() and Log.e()
```

> v for Verbose
>
> d for Debug
>
> i for Info
>
> w for Warnings
>
> e for Error

**In your case**

```
Log.d("Key", json.toString() + "");
Log.d("Key", json.get("display") + "");
```

And you look for the values in the log cat, using the "Key"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`CharArrayWriter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/CharArrayWriter.html) to collect the output:

```
CharArrayWriter writer = new CharArrayWriter();
// write your stuff
TextView view = ...
view.setText(writer.toString());
```

You'll have to use the methods available to a `Writer` rather than those of a `PrintStream` such as `System.out` (no `println()` methods).

If you want to use basically the same calls to generate the output, you can create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and wrap it in a `PrintStream`. After writing (and closing the `PrintStream`), retrieve the byte array from the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and convert it to a `String` using one of the `String` constructors. You just have to specify the character encoding you want to use, both when creating the `PrintStream` and when converting the bytes to a `String`.

Another alternative would be to replace printing with simply appending your data to a `StringBuilder`.

A final alternative is simply to append directly to the `TextView`, but that requires converting every piece of output to some sort of `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JsonReader extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
        public void run(){
           JSONObject json =    readJsonFromUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("display"));
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ 
public void run(){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tv );
        tv.setText(json.toString());
        tv.setText(json.get("display"));
}
});

        }
     }).start();

}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

  //move to onCreate
}
}
```